# Jquery sending data 2 times on click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, form-submit

Hi guys why my jquery code send data 2 times when I click?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#send_message').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var data = $("#message_form").serialize();
    $.post(
      "backend/ajax/send_message.php",
      data

    ).done(function(data) {


    }).fail(function() {

    });
  });
});
```

It post 2 times on database in a single click, somebody know why?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you've demonstrated. This means there's an issue conflicting elsewhere. Try `e.stopPropagation();` in combination with `e.preventDefault()` see if it helps.

Comment: I should add `e.stopPropagation();` below `e.preventDefault()` ?

Comment: I updated with the code, still same problem

Comment: I can only assume, which is the operative word here, that something else is interfering or conflicting. Perhaps duplicate code, etc. If you `console.log('here')` in your event handler, does it appear in the console log twice also?

Comment: I added inside `.done(function(data) {`  this `console.log(data);` is just return me the php sent message "message sent" this is also the only jquery script in the page

Comment: If the log only appears once then this code is not the issue. It will be elsewhere and something only you can discover at this moment.

Comment: If I remove `if($dados->execute()){}` from the backend in pdo it just add a single value only, I think the problem is the backend not the jquery

Comment: Yeah I found the problem and the problem is the backend not the jquery, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

fist you change id #send_message1 and #message_form1

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#send_message1').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
 var data = $("#message_form1").serialize();
   $.post(
    "backend/ajax/send_message.php",
    data

   ).done(function(data) {


   }).fail(function() {

 });
});
```

});